# Selecting all inputs by class, sum up their values and display the total

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I would like to write a jQuery script which can sum up some values in a given form.

The form looks like this:

```
<form>
  Product 1
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price_per_unit[]" value="" class="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per unit" />

  Product 2
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price_per_unit[]" value="" class="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per unit" />

  Product 3
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price_per_unit[]" value="" class="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per unit" />

  [...]

  Product n
  <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price_per_unit[]" value="" class="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per unit" />

  <input type="text" name="total_order" id="total_order" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

If a users enters value "2" for quantity and "10" for "price per unit", the total order is "20".

I would like to trigger the sum operation only when a pair of "quantity" and "price per unit" is filled in.

Also, if the user enters quantities and prices for more than one product, the total order must be the sum of those.

**Later edit**
Sorry, I forgot to post my jQuery code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input .quantity').each(function() {
        $('input .price_per_unit').each(function() {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Fine, you want that. Someone will code that for you if you pay him. (me included) But you should try something first before asking at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to wrap your inputs into something that distinguishes them from each other:

```
<div class='product'>
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
    <input type="text" name="price_per_unit[]" value="" class="price_per_unit" placeholder="Price per unit" />
</div>
```

This will allow us to bind to the pair of inputs inside the .product

Now we bind jQuery:

```
$("body").on("keyup change", ".product input", function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var other = me.parent(".product").find("input").not(me);
    if(other.val() != "") {
        var total = me.val() * other.val();
        //do something with total
        console.log(total);
    }        
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9CWL/3/

Then, you'll take total and display it somewhere, and add its value to the grand total.  You may consider changing the fields to type 'number' - modern browsers will then only allow integer (floating point) numbers based on your settings for the field.

Comment: Thank, Ben, but I'm afraid it's not working correctly for more than one pair of quantity and price per unit.

Comment: Have you wrapped the elements individually? - One product wrapper per pair of inputs?  I've updated the fiddle to have two 'products', open the console and test it. I am seeing what I understand to be the expected results.

Comment: I modified you fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/U9CWL/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/U9CWL/7/) and I get `ReferenceError: total is not defined`.